# Memory leaks with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I profile my iOS application, I found too much Memory leaks:
[image]

There is my code with NSDateFormatter and the code is in one loop:

```
 for (NSDictionary * dataDict in deserializedData) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

Who can tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Are you constantly creating and releasing the NSDateFormatter in a loop? If so, try creating it once and reference the single instance.

Comment: Right， the code is in one loop !

Comment: It looks like the string that is created by it is leaked, from what I can tell. (See how it says 'leaked object: icu::UnicodeString'). Are you assigning the string somewhere and not releasing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with auto release like this,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

for (NSDictionary * dataDict in deserializedData) {
    NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Comment: +1 for creating NSDateFormatter once. But why not also set it up once?

Comment: I changed the code to only set up the formatter once. roll back if you dont like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in this code. But I think it is not called on main thread.

Just create an autorelease pool on the beginning of the function in which you have written this code. At the end of the function release the pool.

```
-(void) yourFun
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //other stuff...

    for (NSDictionary * dataDict in deserializedData) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        [dateFormatter release];
    }

    [pool release];
}
```